# Cleaning datasets with lot of NAs only in some columns

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-cleaning

I have a dataset which has close to 190 columns and 20000 rows. Now some of the columns(close to 70 columns) have approximately 19500 rows with NAs. I am considering two approaches:
1) Remove columns with lot of NA values
2) Remove Rows with NA values

Approach 2 would leave me with a dataset of 500 rows and 120 columns substantially reducing my training dataset. Approach 1 might remove some of the important features.

How should i go about approaching this problem.

Comment: there is no programming or even statistical answer to that question. It depends on what the columns and rows are and what you want to use them for.

Comment: That is not a straightforward problem and will depend on what your data looks like. You have several options: impute them based on what else you know about those samples, remove them which hurts your dataset terribly, or set average values to minimize their effect. The last option should be fine if the source of the missing value is random. For the first one you need to make sure there is an observable correlation between the features